# Extract filename without extension from the absolute location

Tags: substring

I'm trying to get a filename contained in the value of a specific column of my table. My table looks like this:

```
absolutel_path
\\Path\filename.extension
```

I need to extract the filename (in the above `filename`) from the `absolute_path` (`\\Path\filename.extension`). Which function should I use to get my filename (substring) out?

Comment: Which RDBMS server are you using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Edit:

Even though my first solution answered the question as asked, I saw @DavidBoho 's [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/249040/34007) and he made several good points. He suggested that if the filename is `my_file.tar.gz` then the return value should be `my_file.tar` and also that my solution would fail in the event that the file had no extension at all. All of the code here is available on this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e23a824af0f339739729fd3fc978053a).

Given the table and data as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE with_filename
(
  file_id INTEGER,
  file_name VARCHAR (256)
);
```

populate:

```
INSERT INTO with_filename
VALUES
(1, '/users/mcm1/ualaoip2/vmm/file1.pdf'),
(2, '/users/mcm1/ualaoip2/vmm/file2.py'),
(3, '/users/mcm1/ualaoip2/vmm/file3.pdf'),
(4, '/users/mcm1/ualaoip2/vmm/file4.c'),
(5, '/users/mcm1/ualaoip2/vmm/file5.java'),
(6, '/users/mcm1/ualaoip2/vmm/file6.class'),
(7, '/users/mcm1/ualaoip2/vmm/file7'),
(8, '/users/mcm1/ualaoip2/vmm/file8.tar.gz'),
(9, '/users/mcm1/my_prog.cpp');
```

My original solution:

```
SELECT LEFT(
      RIGHT(file_name, POSITION('/' IN REVERSE(file_name)) - 1),
                       POSITION('.' IN 
      RIGHT(file_name, POSITION('/' IN REVERSE(file_name)) - 1)) - 1
) AS my_file
FROM with_filename;
```

gives the result:

```
my_file
file1
file2
file3
file4
file5
file6
file       -- << should be file7
file8      -- << should be file8.tar
my_prog
```

After reading @DavidBoho's post, he used the [`SPLIT_PART`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-string.html) function to resolve the problems with files 7 & 8 - see the fiddle. I decided to look again at my own SQL and I came up with this (perhaps more traditional?):

```
SELECT 
      REPLACE(SUBSTRING(file_name, (LENGTH(file_name) + 2) - POSITION('/' IN REVERSE(file_name))),
      RIGHT(file_name, POSITION('.' IN LEFT(REVERSE(file_name), POSITION('/' IN REVERSE(file_name)) - 1))),
      '') AS the_files
    FROM with_filename
```

Result:

```
the_files
file1
file2
file3
file4
file5
file6
file7
file8.tar
my_prog
```

which is **also** the correct answer!

While I was grasping for a solution, I became interested in regular expressions as a means of solving this problem. Even though I (we) was/were able to solve this using "traditional" SQL, it became clear to me that regexes are extremely powerful and even though SQL is now [Turing complete](https://beza1e1.tuxen.de/articles/accidentally_turing_complete.html), it could rapidly  become extremely convoluted for relatively simple string manipulation  problems, so I decided to investigate.

I found two regex solutions - in fairness, I can't claim to have done this myself, the solutions are as a result of a question I asked on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61606249/postgresql-regexp-split-to-table-i-want-to-get-the-file-name-without-extension). So, the regex solutions are as follows:

The best one is this one -

```
SELECT
    file_name,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(file_name, '^.*/([^/]*?)(\.[^/.]+)?$', '\1') AS filename
FROM with_filename;
```

There is a second one, but IMHO (and that of the original author) it's a bit of a hack - it involves two nested [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP)s

```
SELECT
    file_name,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(file_name, '^.*/(.*)$', '\1'), '\.[^.]+$', '') AS filename
FROM with_filename
```

Finally, there may be a solution possible using the UNNEST and the STRING_TO_ARRAY functions together - I came up with this code:

```
SELECT fn,  
    LEFT(fn, POSITION('.' IN fn) - 1) AS lef
FROM with_filename w,
  UNNEST(STRING_TO_ARRAY(w.file_name, '/')) AS fn
GROUP BY fn
HAVING COUNT(fn) = 1
ORDER BY lef;
```

which gives the result:

```
fn  lef
file7   file       -- << should be file7
file1.pdf   file1
file2.py    file2
file3.pdf   file3
file4.c     file4
file5.java  file5
file6.class     file6
file8.tar.gz    file8  -- << should be file8.tar
my_prog.cpp     my_prog
```

I tried lots of different permutations with this, but couldn't get it to work. Would be grateful for any input! :-)

Another interesting function is REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE.

```
SELECT 
  fn, 
  COUNT(fn)
FROM
(
  SELECT REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE(w.file_name, '/') AS fn
  FROM with_filename w
) AS sq
GROUP BY fn
HAVING COUNT(fn) = 1
ORDER BY fn
```

Result:

```
fn  count
file1.pdf   1
file2.py    1
file3.pdf   1
file4.c     1
file5.java  1
file6.class     1
file7   1
file8.tar.gz    1
my_prog.cpp     1
```

Again, this might be worth pursuing - didn't have time.

## Example DML/DDL

```
CREATE TABLE with_filename
(
  file_id INTEGER,
  file_name VARCHAR (256)
);

INSERT INTO with_filename
VALUES
(1, '/users/mcm1/ualaoip2/vmm/file1.pdf'),
(2, '/users/mcm1/ualaoip2/vmm/file2.py'),
(3, '/users/mcm1/ualaoip2/vmm/file3.pdf'),
(4, '/users/mcm1/ualaoip2/vmm/file4.c'),
(5, '/users/mcm1/ualaoip2/vmm/file5.java'),
(6, '/users/mcm1/ualaoip2/vmm/file6.class'),
(7, '/users/mcm1/ualaoip2/vmm/file7'),
(8, '/users/mcm1/ualaoip2/vmm/file8.tar.gz'),
(9, '/users/mcm1/my_prog.cpp');
```

Comment: I tried to explain this a little better feel free to roll it back if you don't approve.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little late to this party, but I will also share my solution that will also handle some corner cases, that are not covered by the [answer of Vérace](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/190985/191171).

There are two concepts for filename without extension:

1. **without last** extension `filename.tar.gz` ⇨ `filename.tar` (common concept of filename)
2. **without any** extension `filename.tar.gz` ⇨ `filename`

In all implementations I have found so far, filename refers to the **first** concept. So only the last part is treated as extension and the rest as filename.

The [solution of Vérace](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/190985/191171) instead implemented the **second** concept and his solution also fail in two corner cases:

- no directory in the path `filename.tar.gz`
- no extension in the path `filename`

There are also some other cases that you should keep in mind for a possible solution:

- dots in directory names or relative paths e.g.: `../filename-without-ext`

You can find **both** implementations in the [DB Fiddle here...](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jwtGAVPcndvWKqdSunvVyf/2)

## Solution common concept `dir/filename.tar.gz` ⇨ `filename.tar`

```sql
 SELECT LEFT(
                -- The last path segment a.k.a. basename
                REVERSE(SPLIT_PART(REVERSE(path), '/', 1)),
                -- The length of the basename
                LENGTH(SPLIT_PART(REVERSE(path), '/', 1))
                    -- The length of the extension (with dot) in the basename
                    - STRPOS(SPLIT_PART(REVERSE(path), '/', 1), '.')
            ) as filename
 FROM samples
```

The solution in detail. At first we get the last segment of the path (a.k.a. basename) by this combination:

```
REVERSE(SPLIT_PART(REVERSE(path), '/', 1))
```

Next we will calculate the length of the filename to strip this of with `LEFT` to the basename. So we subtract the length of the basename with the length of the extension and the dot. The length of the extension including the dot is the same as the position of the dot from the right.

```
LENGTH(basename) - STRPOS(REVERSE(basename), '.')
```

**Remark:**
There are still two corner cases that are not covered by this solution. But this two cases will also handled differently in common implementations.

1. The current dir and parent dir "filename" `dir/.` and `dir/..`

In [C++ stem](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/stem) 
`fs::path("dir/.").stem()` ⇨ `.` 
`fs::path("dir/..").stem()` ⇨ `..`

In [PHP pathinfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) 
`pathinfo('dir/.', PATHINFO_FILENAME)` ⇨  
`pathinfo('dir/..', PATHINFO_FILENAME)` ⇨ `.`

2. "hidden" files e.g.: `.profile`

In [C++ stem](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/stem) 
`fs::path("dir/.profile").stem()` ⇨ `.profile`

In [PHP pathinfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) 
`pathinfo('dir/.profile', PATHINFO_FILENAME)` ⇨

### Not common concept solution `dir/filename.tar.gz` ⇨ `filename`

Just for completeness here is a solution **without any** extensions:

```
SPLIT_PART(REVERSE(SPLIT_PART(REVERSE(path), '/', 1)), '.', 1)
```

Comment: In the light of your answer, I considerably revised my own one. I'd be interested in your comment - I tried to take on board the points you made - I also upvoted your answer because, a) it was good and b) I learnt a shedload revising my own.